# How to have a function in a server fire off daily

Tags: function, server

I am wondering if there is a way to have a function fire off on a server each day, for example in my MERN stack program lets say i want to do a monthly cleanup of inactive users, and i want to delete them completely but instead of doing this individually or by hitting an endpoint, i just want it to fire off at a certain time, lets say every 30 days this function should run, the logic of the function not being important here but the call to the function being necessary.

I know in a windows server I can accomplish this by writing out a script that the server could activate at a certain time, but im wondering if i can accomplish this within my webserver itself the code, instead.

Comment: A webserver is a service running on a server.  It is unclear from your question if your "MERN stack program" is running on this Windows server, then see [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page), or if it is on Linux/Unix, where crontab can be used to schedule tasks. see: [crontab](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)

Comment: @Luuk yes, the point here though is im trying to discern if there is a way outside of Task Scheduler or crontab to implement the same kind of feature, if there is a way i can write the logic inside of my webapp to fire off even on a daily basis to do something, even if that something is sending a text message that says hello. Because i want to be able to keep my logic in one place, im not 100% sure, but i believe TS/ct i would need to write a script to store on the server itself to have it run said script, correct? id rather just have the script fire off from within my webserver

Comment: Yes, you could write a script which fires when visiting (i.e. `http://example.com/MonthlyCleanUpInavtiveUsers`), but you still need a task scheduler to start this. (Or manually start it every day yourself). Downside is that you need some kind of protection, so not the whole world can run this script.

Comment: @Luuk have any idea what this kind of protection might look like?